# APPIUM: I have a list of elements that in a group that represent notifications, how can I close them all at once?

Tags: java, android, appium

```
[@resource-id="alert_banner_0"]
```

These appear in the app as banner notifications that appear on login when I view it in Appium Inspector. I am trying to find a method or way using Java and Appium that I can use to close all at once i.e., alert_banner_0 thru alert_banner_x versus having to tap and close each one individually. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Currently closing notifications individually.